# Why are my laptop fans spinning all the time at high speed even though CPU usage is under 20%?

Tags: 18.04, asus, fan

I am using an ASUS ROG GL553VD. When I use Windows everything is okay, but in ubuntu 18.04 (actually, in all versions) it keeps running fans all the time even though the CPU usage is under 20%.After fresh install the fan was running normally but when i was trying to shutting down the laptop was freezing.. And to solve that freezing problem  I installed the NVIDIA driver and the fan spinning problem began..

Comment: Your laptop has a Nvidia graphics. Have you installed the drivers? If so, which version? Please [edit] and update the question.

Comment: Edited...@GabrielaGarcia

Comment: I have the same issue with my ASUS ROG FX305VD. Removing the Nvidia drivers solves the problem. But at the same time, I can't enjoy my games. :/

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a software problem. After a few years, the thermal compound that's sandwiched between the CPU and the heatsink becomes hard and brittle and doesn't conduct much. If you're able to get to it, I recommend buying a kit that includes:

- a cleaner to get the old heatsink off
- a prep compound to prepare the CPU surface for the new thermal compound
- and the thermal compound itself.

One thing you might try first to make sure it's not a software issue, is to boot from a LiveCD, open a few browser tabs like you described, and see if the fans race. If they do, it's very likely the hardware issue I described.

Comment: If the CPU would overheat at 20%, the windows system would shut off after a few minutes. But he says everything is OK, so it's unlikely.

Comment: Indeed. If it works as expected in Windows there's no reason to suspect hardware issues. Please read the question carefully before answering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Eric...But I don't think there is a hardware issue..

Answer (score 1):

If you have not installed any of the power management services in Ubuntu, you may find these to be helpful:

First, install Tlp, Thermald, and Lmsensors to create power sensing and management.  From the terminal:

```
sudo apt install tlp thermald
sudo apt install --install-suggests lm-sensors psensor
```

There are configuration files for Tlp located in `/etc/default/tlp` which you can customize to fit your needs.  You can issue `sudo tlp start` to start the process, but I would reboot.

Secondly, there are a set of utilities to set the fan speeds for various sensed temperatures.  The following is quoted from https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1165469-control-fan-speeds-lm_sensors-isnt-working/?tab=comments#comment-595825859

> ```
> sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
> sudo sensors-detect
> ```
>
> just follow the prompts. Add the recommended lines to /etc/modules.
>
> Now, if you don't want to reboot, you'll have to manually activate the
>   modules.
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe module1 module2
> ```
>
> where module1 etc. = the module names provided from sensors-detect.
>
> Next, you need to create your fancontrol file. The easiest way is to
>   run pwmconfig.
>
> ```
> sudo pwmconfig
> ```
>
> and work your way through the instructions there.
>
> Finally, run sensors -s to make your fan configuration take effect.
>
> ```
> sudo sensors -s
> ```
>
> Now, you can check your temps.
>
> ```
> sensors
> ```
>
> Now to run fan control, type:
>
> ```
> sudo /usr/sbin/fancontrol &
> ```
>
> A nice way to visually inspect temps is with  gkrellm. To get it:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gkrellm
> ```

Comment: I suspect this has to due with Nvida running with `nouveau` instead of the proprietary drivers. I never had to install the things you recommend here.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Depends upon the laptop, I think.  My (admittedly older) Dell has in some releases, had a tremendous heat problem, and without Tlp, my battery life is nill.  I think it was 18.04, my fans used to spool up at login...

Comment: I'm waiting for some reply to my comment under the question. The reasons for my suspicions are a high-end gaming laptop with a current Nvidia card + newbie + lack of Nvidia drivers (a knowledgeable user with this problem and Nvidia drivers would have mentioned it in the question, I think).

Comment: I'm of the impression that it the NVidia drivers were not loaded, then the card would be inactive and either an on-board video or llvmpipe would be used.  The llvmpipe would result in high CPU and temperatures .  Tlp and Thermald would assist and Psensors would visually show high temps internal to the box...

Comment: There are open-source and proprietary drivers for Nvidia cards. The problem happens with `nouveau`, the default open-source driver. Proprietary drivers that really works need to be explicitly installed but are available at the Ubuntu repositories or the graphics drivers PPA. `nouveau` has poor support for newer chips.

Comment: @CharlesGreen this is the output for pwmconfig
Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon1/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
See doc/fan-divisors for more information.

Comment: @DiptoMondal Please execute `sudo sensors-detect`

Comment: @DiptoMondal Made major revision to answer...